# What is the "with" modifying in this sentence "He was watching the monster with a smile."

Tags: meaning, grammar, ambiguity

I'm reading such a sentence and confused by the "with":

```
He was watching the monster with a smile.
```

(Let's say there is a kind of monster can smile.)

Who is smiling? He or the monster?

Is there an ambiguity here? If there is how can I correctly express the meaning?